# How can I create a message hash in Solidity that matches Viem?

Tags: solidity, signature, hash, keccak, viem

I'm creating a message [hash with Viem](https://viem.sh/docs/utilities/hashMessage.html#hashmessage) in typescript and in Solidity, however, I can't seem to get the hash in Solidity to match the one created with Viem.

My viem code:

```js
const hashedMessage = hashMessage("test");
console.log("hashed message:", hashedMessage);
// hashed message: 0x4a5c5d454721bbbb25540c3317521e71c373ae36458f960d2ad46ef088110e95
```

But when I try to do the same thing in Solidity, I can't figure out the correct syntax to get the same hash.

```js
function returnHashedMsg() public pure returns (bytes32) {
        string memory test = "test";
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(test)
        );
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", hash.length, hash)
        );
        return messageHash;
    }
```

hash - `0xada625be259fe1e28a18f93e8b9721ea032a2e1b96677d7fc3eaad5fd8b49387`

```js
 function returnHashedMsg() public pure returns (bytes32) {
        string memory test = "test";
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", test)
        );
        return messageHash;
    }
```

hash - `0x45f373debb8d5a53c7df499f79affafa8497c0a91018f7f82fbb3666c8c5563f`

```js
function returnHashedMsg() public pure returns (bytes32) {
        string memory test = "test";
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", bytes(test).length, test)
        );
        return messageHash;
    }
```

hash - `0x6b949bebd615f903fc43643801c27334884c09c74a0e471669a5263baf25be38`

```js
function returnHashedMsg() public pure returns (bytes32) {
        string memory test = "test";
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(test)
        );
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", uint256(bytes(test).length), hash)
        );
        return messageHash;
    }
```

hash - `0x8e23f6de1e62fecf3011ff54e8d44ec446f89506a0cf1a33cb99aff27d3287e4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EIP-191, `len(message)` is the **string representation** of the decimal number of bytes the message takes when encoded in UTF-8, not a literal byte value<sup>1</sup>.

You were closest in the third example you gave. Instead of `bytes(test).length` (which becomes a literal byte value `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004`), you need to pass in the string `"4"` (which becomes a literal byte value `0x34` when encoded in UTF-8).

Unfortunately there's not currently any built-in way in Solidity to convert a `uint256` to its `string` equivalent. However, [OpenZeppelin's `utils/Strings`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/utils#Strings) provides a [`Strings.toString`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/88211e8fbad2e690e62c0dbfc4b14b2d2b6ab566/contracts/utils/Strings.sol#L24) function you can use.

Full example:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

// ...

function returnHashedMsg() public pure returns (bytes32) {
    string memory test = "test";
    string memory len = Strings.toString(bytes(test).length); // "4"
    bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", len, test)
    );
    return messageHash;
}
```

This updated function returns `0x4a5c5d454721bbbb25540c3317521e71c373ae36458f960d2ad46ef088110e95`.

---

<sup>1</sup> EIP-191 isn't precise about this and this decision has been [questioned before](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14794). However, the subsequent [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) adopted the same convention and used more precise language to clear this up.